# commands defined in external file and imported by lua are not recognized

Tags: macros, luatex, input, lua

Suppose I have a file `sourced.tex` which defines a new command `\MyCommand`:

```
\newcommand{\MyCommand}{Hello World}
```

If I create a file `main.tex` and I source this file with `\input`, I'm able to use the command and my document compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \input{sourced.tex}
    \MyCommand
\end{document}
```

However, if I create a file `main_lua.tex` and I source this file using a `lua` interpreter, the file does not compile and I get an error stating that the control sequence is undefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{luacode*}
        tex.print("\\input{sourced.tex}")
    \end{luacode*}
    \MyCommand
\end{document}
```

Does LaTeX code generated in the `lua` terminal not transfer its definitions to the main document? Is there any way around this?

Comment: use `\directlua` ,  `\begin{luacode*}` is an environment so all local definitions such as `\newcommand` are lost at the `\end`

Comment: Thanks David. Is that because `\begin{luacode}` is a "group"? Are environments a subset of groups?

Comment: all environments are groups, your code is like `\begin{empty} \newcommand{\MyCommand}{Hello World}\end{empty} \MyCommand` which you can try in classic tex without Lua at all.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand it a bit better. If you post your first comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{empty} \newcommand{\MyCommand}{Hello World}\end{empty}
\MyCommand
\end{document}
```

which you can try in classic tex without Lua at all. All local definitions such as `\newcommand` are lost at the `\end`

this is one of many reasons I find it easier to use `\directlua` rather than the wrappers provided by `luacode`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\directlua{tex.print("\string\\input{sourced}")}

\MyCommand
\end{document}
```